# Skipping my while statement and just printing 63 numbers for my array

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

So when I run this my program skips the everything and prints out a 63 number array, If I take out the while statements it will run and print out an array with the number I enter for input. I was just trying to figure out why it is not doing the error check, I had a similar program where I typed it the exact same way and It worked.

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<stdlib.h>
  3 #include<time.h>
  4
  5 int check_input(int);
  6 void initialize_array(int array[],int);
  7 void print_array(int array[],int);
  8 void display_menu();
  9 int check_option(int);
 10 int common_numbers(int array[],int array2[],int);
 11 int count_numbers(int array[],int,int);  
 12 int mode(int array[],int);
 13 void print_histogram(int array[],int array2[],int);
 14
 15 #define MAX 100
 16
 17 int main()
 18 {
 19     int a[MAX];
 20     int b[MAX];
 21     int i;
 22
 23     while (check_input(i) == 0)
 24     {
 25         printf("\n Enter the size of the input:");
 26         scanf("%d", &i);
 27
 28         while (check_input(i) == 0)
 29
 30         {
 31             printf("\n Invalid input, enter the input again:");
 32             scanf("%d", &i);
 33         }
 34
 35         check_input(i);
 36     }
 37
 38
 39
 40
 41     initialize_array(a, i);
 42
 43     printf("\n Input array\n");
 44     print_array(a, i);
 45
 46 }
 47
 48 void initialize_array(int array[], int size)
 49 {
 50     srand(time(NULL));
 51     int x;
 52
 53     for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
 54     {
 55         array[x] = rand()%10;
 56     }
 57 }
 58
 59 int check_input(int a)
 60 {
 61     if(a > 0 || a <= 100)
 62     {
 63     a = 1;
 64     
 65     return a;
 66     }
 67 
 68     else 
 69     {
 70     a = 0;
 71     
 72     return a;
 73     }
 74 }
 75
 76 void print_array(int array[], int size)
 77 {
 78     int x;
 79
 80     for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
 81     {
 82         printf("%d ", array[x]);
 83     }
 84
 85     printf("\n");
 86 }
```

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers if you don't use them in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program provokes undefined behavior, `i` should be initialized. `-1` will be good init value for `i`. So for begining

```
 int i =-1;
```

And then change the condition in `check_input` to

```
if(a > 0 && a <= 100)
```

as you want `i` to be between `0` and `100`. Asking

```
if(a > 0 || a <= 100)
```

will always give `true` .

Comment: I fail to understand how @Dabo answer helped you and mine didn't, since they are virtually the same. But life goes on :-D you should accepted his answer if it helped you

Comment: @Streppel i started with explanation regarding init value, and you edit your answer with explanation of init value later. Maybe he read my post first  :))))

Comment: I doubt that's it, because I edited my init value a few seconds after I posted the answer. But, whatever. Upvoted your answer anyway, since it is also correct.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to change your condition

```
if(a > 0 || a <= 100)
```

to

```
if(a > 0 && a <= 100)
```

so that you can garantee that `a` will always be between 0 and 100. Otherwise, your `if` statement will always be true.

Also, you should initialize your variable `i`, like this

```
int i = 0;
```

or it will be an variable with undefined value.

There are a couple more improvements that you can make on your code:

1. there is no need for your `check_input(i);` call, at line 35.
2. You don't need to set a value to your `a` variable within your `check_input()` function. Just `return 1;` or `return 0;` instead of `return a;`

Comment: I changed that and It's still doing the same thing.

Comment: @user3427697 Is it still skipping your first `while` check? [because it works here](https://ideone.com/N3azSi)